# How to mask paddings in LSTM model for speech emotion recognition

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

Given a few directories of .wav audio files, I have extracted their features in terms of a 3D array (batch, step, features).

For my case, the training dataset is (1883,100,136).
Basically, each audio has been analyzed 100 times (imagine that as 1fps) and each time, 136 features have been extracted. However, those audio files are different in length so some of them cannot be analyzed for 100 times.

For instance, one of the audio has 50 sets of 136 features as effective values so the rest 50 sets were padded with zeros.

Here is my model.

```
def LSTM_model_building(units=200,learning_rate=0.005,epochs=20,dropout=0.19,recurrent_dropout=0.2):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(LSTM(units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout, input_shape=(X_train.shape[0],100, 136))))
#     model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(LSTM(32)))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    
    adamopt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8)
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=learning_rate, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-6)
#     opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9, decay=0., nesterov=False)
    
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=adamopt,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs=epochs,
              validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                        verbose = 1)

    score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test,
                                batch_size=batch_size)
    return history
```

I wish to mask the padding however the instruction, shown on the [Keras website](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding), uses an `embedding layer` which I believe is usually used for NLP. I have no idea how to use the `embedding layer` for my model.

Can anyone teach me how to apply masking for my LSTM model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Embedding` layer is not for your case. You can consider instead `Masking` [layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Masking). It is simply integrable in your model structure, as shown below.

I also remember you that the input shape must be specified in the first layer of a sequential model. Remember also that you don't need to pass the sample dimension. In your case, the input shape is `(100,136)` which is equal to `(timesteps,n_features)`

```
units,learning_rate,dropout,recurrent_dropout = 200,0.005,0.19,0.2
num_classes = 3

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(100,136)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(LSTM(units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout)))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

adamopt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8)
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=learning_rate, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-6)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=adamopt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I noticed that the `input_shape` parameter written by you as a 2D array which suggested that the model can automatically identify the 1st dimension of X_train is the batch or we can name it the index of the datasets? I ask this question because I put the whole shape of my training dataset for `input_shape` as shown in my codes. Was I wrong ? @Marco Cerliani

Comment: Yes, it is wrong. as I reported keras doesn't need the sample dimensionality. it is automatically inferred during the training process in order to split the data into batches. Don't forget to upvote and accept it ;-)

Comment: `mask_value=0.0` was set, and I check my datasets, those zeros were written as `0.00E+00`. Will the mask work as the number of demical places differs? @Marco Cerliani

Comment: yes it's not a problem... Don't forget to upvote and accept it ;-)

Comment: Yes, I did, would you mind to take a look at my another simple question regarding the normalization of a 3D array?